# Paytm IOS Swift with latest SDK Invalid CheckSum

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, paytm

**I have Integrated Paytm Latest SDK and i have attached the following code below I am getting Invalid CheckSum this as response What is the issue i am facing Please Help me out**

```
var txnController = PGTransactionViewController()
```

```
       var serv = PGServerEnvironment()
       serv = serv.createProductionEnvironment()
       let type :ServerType = .eServerTypeProduction
       let order = PGOrder(orderID: "", customerID: "", amount: "", eMail: "", mobile: "")
       order.params = ["MID": "thiHMw75742998020160",
                       "ORDER_ID": "1520843747890",
                       "CUST_ID": "1",
                       "MOBILE_NO": "9876543210",
                       "EMAIL": "demo@demo.com",
                       "CHANNEL_ID": "WAP",
                       "WEBSITE": "WEBSTAGING",
                       "TXN_AMOUNT": "100.12",
                       "INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID": "Retail",
                       "CHECKSUMHASH": "oCDBVF+hvVb68JvzbKI40TOtcxlNjMdixi9FnRSh80Ub7XfjvgNr9NrfrOCPLmt65UhStCkrDnlYkclz1qE0uBMOrmuKLGlybuErulbLYSQ=",
                       "CALLBACK_URL": "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=1520843747890",
                       "REQUEST_TYPE":"DEFAULT"]

       self.txnController =  (self.txnController.initTransaction(for: order) as?PGTransactionViewController)!
       self.txnController.title = "Paytm Payments"
       self.txnController.setLoggingEnabled(true)
       if(type != ServerType.eServerTypeNone) {
           self.txnController.serverType = type;
       } else {
           return
       }
       self.txnController.merchant = PGMerchantConfiguration.defaultConfiguration()
       self.txnController.delegate = self
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.txnController, animated: true)


   }
```

Comment: "i have attached the following code" - perhaps you forgot to include. Please add the code

Comment: @SahilManchanda i have added the code above please check it out

Comment: Are you generating the checksum on server?

Comment: @SahilManchanda yes iam generating checksum from backend

Comment: then make sure the details are same and you are using all the required parameters

Comment: @SahilManchanda yes all are same only i have checked twice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199899/discussion-between-sahil-manchanda-and-sudarvizhi-s).